What's the proper error metric for a 'guessed' result when comparing with the observation data?
Hi Statisticians/Mathematicians,
I am trying to compute the error of a 'guessed' value against some observation data, and am wondering what's the right process/approach.
For example, there is a group A of 10,000 people. John came and made a random guess that the average height of group A is 60 inches.
Now we randomly pick 100 people from Group A, the mean and the std of the picked 100 people are:
mean = 61 inches
std = 1 inch
Then how do I report the error about John's guess (60 inches)? What kind of metric is suggested? Would really appreciate some advice. Thanks!

There is no mathematical "proper" answer to your question. What you decide to report is just a convention, which you should explain to your audience.
I would suggest reporting how many standard deviations the guess is from the mean. In this case it would be just $1$.
